# Why regular expression is not working, python?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to pull url from inside of html but seems that regex is not working. Any issue spotted ? Though when i take only a part of html for my website it works fine(have commented out that part of code)

I do know about scapy and beautifulSoap etc. but for due to restriction i don't want to use such modules.

```
    page="ANY-XYZ-WEBSITE"

    def extract_first_link():
        urlopener=urllib.urlopen(page)
        html=str(urlopener.read())
        matchObj = re.match( '<a href="(.*)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)"', html, re.I)
        #k = open ("file.txt",'w')
        #k.write(html)
        #print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group(1)
        #matchObj = re.match( '<a href="(.*)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)"', html[4111:4150], re.M|re.I)
        print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
        print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group(1)
        print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group(2)

    if __name__=="__main__":
        print extract_first_link()
```

Comment: I think you need to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`. `match` will only look at the beginning of the string.

Comment: try replacing `(.*)` with `([^/]*)`

Comment: OOPs , thanks for  pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re.match checks only the beginning of the string, re.search searches all the string.

Described here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html